# How to make loops iterate faster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, primes

I have never had this problem before.
I am trying to generate very large prime numbers.
The problem is that the program is way too slow to be of any good use.
When I modified the code to show every num it goes trough it still appears to be slow with large numbers.
Is there any way to make Python(3) loop faster?
If not, is there a way to make my program any faster?

My_Code

```
import os, time, random

lower = 100000000000000000
upper = 999999999999999999

fh = open("pit.txt", "w+")

print("Starting...")

x = 0

for num in range(lower, upper + 1):
    x = x + 1
    if num > 1:
       for i in range(2, num):
           if (num % i) == 0:
               break
       else:
           print("KEY_CODE = " + str(x))
           print(num)
           fh.write(str(num) + ",")
print("Done.")
fh.close()
```

PS: I forgot to mention that the program writes the values into a text document.
I don't suspect that it's slowing the program down since nothing gets printed anyway.

Comment: Different solution, but there's a faster prime generation algorithm called the Sieve of Erastosthenes that you could use to speed things up: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: For starters, you can cut the time in half by incrementing `num` by 2 at each step. 2 is the only even prime.

Comment: It's a problem of your basic, but inefficient primalty test. This is working for numbers below 1e6, but not for the range you provided. Look at implementation for efficient primalty tests like Miller-Rabin, Sieve of Erathosthenes or something like that.

Comment: You're trying to loop over a range of almost a *quintillion* numbers and generate *quadrillions* of primes. Even if you could generate one prime per nanosecond, this would take years, and you'd run out of disk space in seconds.

Comment: I have tried using the Sieve of Eratosthenes and it is still extremely inefficient.

Comment: Is this just impossible to do with my limited computing power and time?

Comment: The best way is often to implement a better algorithm.

Comment: Yes, your algorithm cannot be made fast enough for large numbers. You need a more advanced algorithm.

Comment: sympy has a suite of methods for [finding primes](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html) that might be of interest.  might be worth looking at the source code to see what they do or even just using the library

Answer (score 1):

All large primes are of the form `6n±1`.  Generate a random number of that form in the range you need.  Then test the number using the Miller-Rabin test.  That will find a large prime a lot faster than your current method.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a very quick primefinder in a range you specify. if you want a better isprime test you can import isprime from sympy instead:

```
import random
import math 

def isprime(hm, iterx=150):
   for x in range(iterx):
     if pow(random.randint(2,hm-1), hm-1, hm) != 1:
        return False
   return True

def prime_finder(start, end, primeanswer=False, withstats=True):
    while True:
       randnum = random.randint(start, end*2)
       while math.gcd(randnum, 1<<randnum.bit_length()) == 2 and isprime(randnum//2) == False:
         randnum = random.randint(start, end*2)
       answer = randnum//2
       # This option makes the finding of a prime much longer, i would suggest not using it as 
       # the whole point is a prime result. 
       if primeanswer == True:
          if isprime(answer) == False:
            continue
       powers2find = pow(answer, randnum-1, randnum)
       if powers2find == answer:
          continue
       if powers2find < start or powers2find > end:
          continue
       if isprime(powers2find) == True:
          break
       else:  
          continue
    if withstats == False:
      return powers2find
    elif withstats == True:
      return f"pow({answer}, {randnum}-1, {randnum}) = {powers2find}"
    return powers2find
```

Results:

```
In [2]:  prime_finder(100000000000000000,999999999999999999)                                                                                                                      
Out[2]: 'pow(106974006956583922, 213948013913167845-1, 213948013913167845) = 144873055261278481'

In [3]:  prime_finder(100000000000000000,999999999999999999)                                                                                                                      
Out[3]: 'pow(428583304152980488, 857166608305960977-1, 857166608305960977) = 527820433483021711'

In [4]:  prime_finder(100000000000000000,999999999999999999)                                                                                                                      
Out[4]: 'pow(325303586907911770, 650607173815823541-1, 650607173815823541) = 160187520431555971'
```

You can run it like this to just get an answer:

```
In [10]:  prime_finder(100000000000000000,999999999999999999,withstats=False) 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[10]: 443393963672858509
```

Comment: I have a large prime finder called random_powers_of_2_prime_finder(powersof2num) here if your interested: https://github.com/oppressionslayer/primalitytest